# ggplot2: stat_summary -where does the "min" in "fun.min" come from?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Apologies beforehand, I am new to coding and am learning R from here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#statistical-transformations

Using tidyverse package with ggplot2

There is a section at the end where we are plotting the "diamonds" dataset using "stat_summary":

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
    fun.min = min,
    fun.max = max,
    fun = median
  )
```

**Where/how do "min", "max", "median" from the above code get defined?** I understand that these summary functions (fun.min, fun.max, and fun) take numeric vectors and output a single number summary, but I cannot find any documentation saying where these "min", "max", and "median" vectors get defined nor can I find the answers in the solutions manual (https://jrnold.github.io/r4ds-exercise-solutions/data-visualisation.html#statistical-transformations)

Thank you!

Comment: `min/max/median` are `base R` functions

Comment: @akrun so how do these `base R` functions get fed the depth vector? Usually with functions you have to do something like `min(diamonds$depth)`

Comment: If you check the source code of `stat_summary` the inputs are fed into another function `layer`

Comment: @akrun Sorry I am still confused: can you explain how 'fun.min' are fed into 'layer', and how 'min' gets fed the depth of diamonds for each specific cut?

Comment: Oh, I finally get it: I think the novel concept for is me that I didn't know that arguments themselves in a function could be defined as another function. `fun.min` gets defined as the `min` (Base R) function. Other arguments from `stat_summary` through `layer` get passed to `fun.min` which gets the minimum of those values!