# How does fun.min, fun.max, and fun work for stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry, I know that this question was practically asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72031033/ggplot2-stat-summary-where-does-the-min-in-fun-min-come-from), however I still don't understand how these summary functions( fun.min, fun.max, fun) truly work. In the manual examples, these functions are oftentimes in the context of and defined as

```
 ggplot(data = <DATA>) + 
  stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(<MAPPINGS>),
    fun.min = min,
    fun.max = max,
    fun = median
  )
```

From what I understand, `fun.min = min` defines the summary function as the `min` base R function, however then what happens? How does `fun.min` know to find the minimum value of our mappings argument? Taking a step back, why does `fun.min` have to even be defined as the `min` base R function, since isn't it already defined as finding the minimum value in a vector and then returning a single number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a simple example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(cyl, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

base + stat_summary(
  fun.min = min,
  fun.max = max,
  fun = median,
  color = "red"
)
```

[image]

Now to your questions:

> From what I understand, `fun.min = min` defines the summary function as the `min` base R function, however then what happens? How does `fun.min` know to find the minimum value of our mappings argument?

Under the hood `stat_summary` aggregates the dataset passed via the `data` argument, i.e. for each value or category of the `x` variable (or in the more general case the interaction of the `x`  and the `group` aesthetic) it computes the three statistics defined by `fun`, `fun.min` and `fun.max` for the variable mapped on the `y` aes. The value computed by `fun` is then mapped on `y`, the value of `fun.min` on `ymin` and the value of `fun.max` on `ymax`.

The result of this step could be made visible via `ggplot2::layer_data`. For the basic example

```r
layer_data(last_plot(), 2) # The 2 means we want the data for the second layer. geom_point = first layer, stat_summary = second layer
#>   x group    y ymin ymax PANEL flipped_aes colour size linetype shape fill
#> 1 4    -1 26.0 21.4 33.9     1       FALSE    red  0.5        1    19   NA
#> 2 6    -1 19.7 17.8 21.4     1       FALSE    red  0.5        1    19   NA
#> 3 8    -1 15.2 10.4 19.2     1       FALSE    red  0.5        1    19   NA
#>   alpha stroke
#> 1    NA      1
#> 2    NA      1
#> 3    NA      1
```

Besides a lot of other stuff added by `ggplot2` that's basically the same as

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

mtcars |> 
  group_by(x = cyl) |> 
  summarise(y = median(mpg), ymin = min(mpg), ymax = max(mpg))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>       x     y  ymin  ymax
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  26    21.4  33.9
#> 2     6  19.7  17.8  21.4
#> 3     8  15.2  10.4  19.2
```

> Taking a step back, why does `fun.min` have to even be defined as the `min` base R function, since isn't it already defined as finding the minimum value in a vector and then returning a single number?

The answer is no. `fun.min` is not defined as the minimum or `min` function. It's `NULL` by default (see `?stat_summary`). `fun.min` provides the function which is used to compute the summary statistic to be mapped on the `ymin` aes.  If `fun.min` would be fixed to the `min`imum, `stat_summary` wouldn't be that useful, e.g. quite often we use `fun.min` and `fun.max` to display a confidence interval or to display the interquartile range:

```
base + stat_summary(
    fun.min = ~quantile(.x, probs = .25),
    fun.max = ~quantile(.x, probs = .75),
    fun = median,
    color = "red"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing explanation. Completely understand it now! I did have a follow up question however; when defining `fun.min` as the base R min function, why don't we need the parentheses around min, such as `min()`? When I've tried experimenting with this in, for example,
`fun.min = min(), fun.max = max(), fun = median()` it throws an error saying `argument "x" is missing,` but I don't understand why. In a more general sense, how does defining one function (`fun.min`) as another function (`max`) work in R? What is the relevant syntax (i.e. why aren't parentheses/arguments needed)?

Comment: Hm. That's not special about `stat_summary`, i.e. in R in general you could do `f <- min` and then do e.g. `f(1, 2, 3)`. In some sense functions in R are not different from variables, i.e. we could assign them to variables or pass them as arguments to other functions which then do soemthing with the passed funtion. That is a quite useful feature. If we instead use e.g. min() then well already call the function and do a computation. In that we pass the result but not the function itself.

Comment: How interesting. So in order to assign a function to a variable without calling it, we do not use the parentheses? What are other common cases where this is done? I've been trying to find other questions/articles about calling a function vs assigning a function to a variable but I can't seem to find any; any places to look?

Comment: Hi Scott. Don't know of any resources. Assigning a function to a variable and using the variable instead of the function is probably not that useful. But let's say you want to apply different functions on a vector. Then your could put the functions in a list and do `mystats <- list(mean = mean, sd = sd); lapply(mystats, function(f) f(c(1, 2, 3)))`.

Answer (score 2):

## What do `fun.min`/`fun.max`/`fun` do?

These functions manipulate different parts of the `ggplot` output. They take a vector of values and produce a single value that is then placed on the figure.

- `fun.min` assigns a value to the lower bounds of an interval. Usually, this is the minimum of the `y` value.
- `fun.max` assigns a value to the upper bounds of the interval. Usually this is the maximum of the `y` value.
- `fun` assigns a value to the dot that is often in the middle of the interval. Usually this is the mean of the `y` value.

You can see this behavior by observing how the plots below vary with the functions passed to these arguments. It helps to think about these as *controlling the interval* - which can represent whatever you want - rather than showing the max, min, and mean. For example, instead of displaying the minimum, maximum, and mean values with the interval, you could show an interval that calculate the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd tertile of values for the vector by passing functions that estimate each of these quantities. Below, I demonstrate passing different functions.

### A plot with the "typical" functions: `min`, `max`, `mean`

```r
set.seed(13)
library(ggplot2)

# An example ggplot
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()

## Default (fun.min = min)
d + stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = min, fun.max = max, colour = "red")
```

[image]

### Pass `fun.min` a function that returns 1

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = function(x){1}, fun.max = max, colour = "red")
```

[image]

### Pass `fun.min` a function that returns a random value from `c(-20, 0, 20)`

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = mean, 
                 fun.min = function(x){sample(c(-20, 0, 20), size = 1, replace = T)}, fun.max = max, colour = "red")
```

[image]

### Pass `fun` a function that returns 1

See the dot move compared to the first plot!

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = function(x){1}, fun.min = min, fun.max = max, colour = "red")
```

[image]

## How does it "know" our mappings?

The documentation notes that it can be ambiguous what vector is actually being passed to these arguments. By default, `ggplot` tries to figure out the orientation of the figure (what variables are on the x versus y axes) and then passes the y-axis values. However, you can set the orientation manually to avoid producing unexpected results.

Here is the description of the `orientation` argument to `stat_summary`:

> The orientation of the layer. The default (NA) automatically
> determines the orientation from the aesthetic mapping. In the rare
> event that this fails it can be given explicitly by setting
> orientation to either "x" or "y". See the Orientation section for more
> detail.

## Alternative `geom` types

While changing the parameters affect the interval in the above examples, it is possible to change the `geom` type within `stat_summary`. Instead of layering an interval defined by 3 points on top of the plot, we could add a line instead. You'll see below that the `fun.min` argument now changes the scale of the axis but not the actual line's values. Nevertheless, `fun` itself affects the line's position.

### `geom = "line"`: typical functions

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = min, fun.max = max, colour = "red", geom = "line")
```

[image]

### `geom = "line"`: pass `fun.min` a function that returns 5

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = mean, fun.min = function(x){5}, fun.max = max, colour = "red", geom = "line")
```

[image]

### `geom = "line"`: pass `fun` a function that returns 5

```r
d + stat_summary(fun = function(x){5}, fun.min = min, fun.max = max, colour = "red", geom = "line")
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. Almost in the same second and using the same example. :D

Comment: 10 seconds! I will also say that the documentation for the `Summary functions` is pretty rough. It descibes `fun.data` pretty well  but doesn't really explain which `aes` is passed - essentially had to play around. Modifying now as well to explain different geoms.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks so much. I had an additional question that is asked on stefan's post, but both posts were very useful. I appreciate the examples